# Unable to get object instead of array

Tags: javascript

Hello I am new to the site, and I have a problem with javascript that I do not know how to fix.

I have an array, which I want to turn into an object.

```js
arr = [
{prefer: "sport_swimming", rating: "1"},
{prefer: "sport_running", rating: "5"},
{prefer: "sport_tennis", rating: "2"},
{prefer: "study_archeology", rating: "4"}];

obj = Object.assign({}, arr);



console.log(obj);
```

I want to get to something like this:

```
{
    "sport": {
        "swimming":"1",
        "running":"5",
        "tennis":"2"
    },
    "study":
    {
        "archeology":"4"
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to reduce it into an object, nothing is doing to do the conversion for you.

Comment: There seems no mapping which converts your array format to object format

Comment: This is not a conversion, you need to parse the data in the array and build the object. Please attempt and post your logic if you run into trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Using reduce you can look over the array and build an object using the keys you split off the property.

```js
const arr = [
  {prefer: "sport_swimming", rating: "1"},
  {prefer: "sport_running", rating: "5"},
  {prefer: "sport_tennis", rating: "2"},
  {prefer: "study_archeology", rating: "4"}
];


const out = arr.reduce((acc, data) => {
  const parts = data.prefer.split("_");
  acc[parts[0]] = acc[parts[0]] || {};
  acc[parts[0]][parts[1]] = data.rating;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce`:

```js
const arr = [
    { prefer: "sport_swimming", rating: "1" },
    { prefer: "sport_running", rating: "5" },
    { prefer: "sport_tennis", rating: "2" },
    { prefer: "study_archeology", rating: "4" }];


const result = arr.reduce((a, e) =>
    ([parent, child] = e.prefer.split('_'),
        (a[parent] ??= {})[child] = e.rating,
        a), {});

console.log(result);
```